# java webservice url encoding

Tags: java, web-services, url, encoding

I host a 10 year old java (jar) based web service on Tomcat.
The original source for this service no longer exists (actually the firm that created the service no longer exists and there doesn't seem to be any way to find the former principals).

I packet captured the "Data" field in the url and include a snip of it below.

I'm hoping someone will recognize the encoding used on this field - it does not appear to be standard where the rest of the URL encoding it no problem.  So I'm thinking the application posting the data field first encodes the field (which is then again encoded for the URL post command.

http:// ... &CompletedBillableTransactionFlag=&Data=%F0j%B2g%1F-%95%F7%E3E%C0q%A6%12%11%B2%7C%D8%C7%F6%C8%24 ... I could have included the rest of the fields value but thought to keep it short.

Comment: It looks like normal url encoding for me, also you could try to decompile the classes in the jar

Comment: I have but of the 80 jars I'm not clear which one receives the URL.

Comment: If it is normal encoding why does it not decode.  Decoding just yields the same string.  Do you have a code snip to try?

Comment: @user2367083 some applications do base64 encoding to hide sensitive data sent in the URL. Did you try decoding this using base64 decoder